# Logarithmically bounded function fulfills $f(n) \le \lceil m \cdot \log_b r \rceil$ for certain numbers $n,m,r$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, inequality, logarithms, arithmetic

Let $f : \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ be a function such that $f(n) \le 1 + \log_b n$ for some base $b$ and all $n$. Now let $n \in \mathbb N$ have the property that
$$
 \frac{r^m - 1}{r-1} \le n < \frac{r^{m+1}-1}{r-1}
$$
for some $m \in \mathbb N$ and $r > 1$ with $r \in \mathbb N$. Does it follow that $f(n) \le \lceil m \cdot \log_b r \rceil$?

Comment: Are we assuming $r>1$?

Comment: Yes! I will edit my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not follow.

Let $b=2$, $r=1.1$, and $m=1$. Let's assume that $f(n) =  1+\lfloor \log_2(n) \rfloor$.

Then $n$ must satisfy $$ 1 \leq n < r+1 = 2.1.$$ So let $n=2$. Then $f(2) = 1 + \log_2(2) = 2$, but the proposed upper bound is $\lceil m \cdot \log_b r \rceil = \lceil \log_2(1.1) \rceil = 1$.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, I meant all values to be integers, so $r \in \mathbb N$ and $r = 1.1$ would not be allowed. I will edit my post..

Comment: And the assumption $f(n) = 1 + \log_2(n)$ is also now valid, as $f(n) \in \mathbb N$ must hold.

Comment: Ok, I see your example even works for $r = 2$, so it shows that even under these stronger assumption the inequality does not hold.

Comment: For some reason, I forgot about the restriction on the codomain; so I fixed f.